# How to set a default value in Symfony2 so that automatic CRUD generated forms don't require those fields?

Tags: php, symfony, crud

As I've already [found out](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/faq.html), Doctrine2 "*does not support to set the default values in columns through the “DEFAULT” keyword in SQL. ... you can just use your class properties as default values*".

```
class Product
{

// ...

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name = "";

    /**
     * @var string $sale
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sale", type="boolean")
     */
    private $sale = false;
```

But even when I do this, the generated CRUD forms still require me to fill out all forms. In case of boolean attributes this even means I can only set it to true (i.e. `1`).

Am I doing something wrong?

(I know I can turn the validation off but I'd like a solution to the problem instead of just bypassing it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your boolean value need to have nullable set as true:

```
/**
 * @var string $sale
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sale", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $sale = false;
```

Answer (score 6):

In Object-oriented programming you should use constructor of the entity to set a default value for an attribute:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->sale = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the CRUD auto-generation tool, but I know that by default, each and every field is required. YOu must explicitly pass `'required' => false` as an option for your fields.

This can be done in the form classes

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('field', 'text', array('required' => false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

The same can be achived in a Form class generated inside your controller

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Foo;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // ...    

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($foo)
            ->add('field', 'text', array('required' => false)
            ->getForm();

        // ...

        return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: This line: " $builder->add('field', 'text', array('required' => false));" solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the 'data' parameter like in :

```
->add('date', 'date', array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'),
                    'data' => new \DateTime()
                ))
```

Here I have set a class to make a jQuery UI datepicker of the field using JavaScript.
I also set the widget to a single_text so I won't get three select fields.
And then I set the default data to the current DateTime()

Answer (score 1):

Or In annotations
Use:

```
options={"default":"foo"}
```

and not:

```
options={"default"="foo"}
```

For instance:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="smallint", options={"default":0})
 */
private $foo;
```